# Connection error thrown when creating docker container

Tags: java, docker, post, containers

I want to create a docker container through the Intellij idea program,
docker run --name my-container2 hello-github:1.0
I get an error:
docker: error during connect: Post "https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.24/containers/create?name=m
y-container2": dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because
the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection f
ailed because connected host has failed to respond.
How can the error be corrected?
Thank You

Comment: Make your Docker daemon listen to TCP.

Comment: What sort of Docker setup are you using?  Did you intentionally set a `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable (maybe using a command like `minikube docker-env` or `docker-machine env`); does unsetting it help?